# Adding android platform to a cordova project not working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

After all prerequisites are working well,
I type the command to add android platform `cordova platform add android` , it displays this message "Adding android project..." and stops,but when I check  the platforms folder I find nothing

Comment: Try to add browser platform. I guess it may fail too. Its something to do with npm and nodejs installation i guess

Comment: Can run again the command like this for get more information: cordova platform add android --verbose

Comment: May be a little dumb, but are you checking the right folder/project ? Otherwise check the verbose as mentioned by Andres